# How to write a custom Feature Parser and Use in Cucumber Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gherkin, cucumber-java

Due to some requirements, I wanted to write a custom feature parser for the cucumber and wanted to keep some functionalities like invoke (run multiple times) and csv support to the examples. But its requiring me to write a custom cucumber main class with cucumber run time.

Is there any way, we can include CustomFeatureParser directly into the cucumber's Main?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I created a CustomCucumber.class for the Junit runner instead of using the native Cucumber.class and a Main class to run the CustomRuntime class which I have modified to include my CustomFeatureParser. It's working But, when I'm using IntelliJ, I have to configure the cucumber template to use my CustomMain to run the feature files